# Read in a line using recursion and return a pointer to the string

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to create a char *read_line(void) function which reads in a character recursively so with each recursive call it creates a local char variable and when enter character has been read in, it can determine how much memory is needed to be allocated so it can eventually return a pointer to a string. The string must end with \0 terminator. I may only use one malloc call, I cannot use any global or static variables or any other containers. I may use any custom helper functions. Prohibited words: realloc;calloc;strcpy;strncpy;10
I know this is impractical, but it's a homework assignment.

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have used to tackle the problem?

Comment: If this is a recursive function you are expected to write, is a maximum amount of characters specified? The stack has a limited amount of recursive calls possible before it overflows.

Comment: It would have been useless to show any code I tried because it was really bad and didn't work, I still struggle with recursion. There is no maximum amount of characters specified, it should work with any amount of characters, of course as long as it doesn't cause stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final call will need to do

```
char *str = malloc(i+1);
str[i] = 0;
return str;
```

Other calls will need to do

```
char *str = read_line_helper(...);
str[i] = ch;
return str;
```

That means that each call needs an `i` that's one more than its caller. This can easily be achieved by passing `i+1` to the recursive function.

```
char *read_line_helper(size_t i) {
   char ch = ...;

   char *str;
   if (...) {
      str = malloc(i+1);
      str[i] = 0;
   } else {
      str = read_line_helper(i+1);
      str[i] = ch;
   }

   return str;
}
```

The first call takes `0`.

```
char *read_line(void) {
   return read_line_helper(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really elegant solution. It works well, and I could easily fill in the blanks, so it was helpful that you gave hints to me to finish the code :)